# Linking Userform Button Labels to VLookup Code

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, userform

Good Evening All,
This is my first time using VBA, so apologies if this question seems pretty trivial.

I have a spreadsheet that lists out Document ref no, doc title, due dates, author etc - there's about 40 in total.

I have set up a "Search" Userform with CommandButtons on which are labels with the doc ref for each document.

I have then created another "Information" Userform with text boxes for all the pertinent information appending to the document. This Userform has a VLookup to go into the spreadsheet and pull all the information associated with a particular doc ref no.

Question: I would like to use the same Information Userform for all the document refs. I would therefore like the VLookup Value to equal the label name from whatever button is pressed on the initial search Userform. Is this possible?

I have managed to do this for one button, but trying to get it to work for multiple buttons baffles me.

For example if I haven't been clear. If I click on the button labelled Document 1 I want the form to drag all the info for document 1, and the same form to do the same thing if I click Document 2 and 3 and so on.

Comment: Are you planning on having a separate event handler for each button on the first form?  Seems like you'd be better off with a "control array" approach as outlined here - http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: Thanks for your response Tim. I'll have a go at that.
I am planning on having a separate event handler for each button on the first form. Although now you've mentioned a control array, it at means I just have to write the code once - that could be better!

Comment: That would be better, but you could also consider just having a listbox on the first form...